# There was an error deploying functions. Failed to update function app in region us-central1

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my first time trying to deploy a function firebase function. I've written an API and I want to create a firebase function and use it.

In my project everything works on localhost and even worked when I did `firebase serve --only functions, hosting`.

Since I'm only using `hosting` and `functions` I didn't do the `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` thing of firebase config (not sure if this is required).

My `functions/index.js` is:

```
//functions/index.js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var connection = require('../utils/dbconfig'); //outside functions folder

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// API START HERE
app.get('/getEmployees', (req, res) => {

    // Here I connect to db which has it's configurations in dbConfig.js
    res.send(result);

});
// API END HERE
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I've pasted this code manually from the `index.js` that I have in the main project folder (outside functions) and inside the `function` folder I've another `index.js`, and `package.json` files which were auto-generated and I have added dependencies as I had in the `package.js` on outside of the `functions` folder. Then inside the `functions` folder, I did `npm install`.

Here is my `functions/package.json` file:

```
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "tedious": "^14.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Then the only `firebase.json` file has these settings:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  }
}
```

When I do `firebase deploy` (that deploys the functions and hosting) or `firebase deploy --only functions` I get an error from which I've taken the last 10 lines:

```
[debug] [2022-03-08T02:48:07.963Z] <<< [apiv2][body] DELETE https://us.gcr.io/v2/ventes-4f9b6/gcf/us-central1/053feedd-aed4-4c8d-93c4-591b134374b6/cache/manifests/sha256:7b2b71f239340ebec209e230e76e303b6fd7293c8f23ee3292f23d8cf4571319 {"errors":[]}
[debug] [2022-03-08T02:48:08.022Z] Error: Failed to update function app in region us-central1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:38:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Fabricator.updateV1Function (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:255:32)
    at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:136:13)
    at async handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:75:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

I've tried different solutions with a similar title, but nothing works so far. I have also tried installing packages again in the `functions` folder, but nothing is wrong for me.

Comment: For future readers: also check your `firebase-tools` or CLI version; seems like Google sometimes introduces breaking API changes that happen across minor (or even patch) CLI/tools releases, and it simply causes the deployment to fail - without the real error being exposed to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have files outside the functions folder. Only what's in the functions folder gets deployed. Move it inside of your functions folder.

```
var connection = require('../utils/dbconfig'); //outside functions folder
```

Also, `functions.https.onRequest` handles [parsing the body of incoming requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request), so using any body parsers will likely lead to errors and you should remove it.